# Is there any way of inspecting an element and seeing from which PHP file is comming from?

Tags: php, file

For instance, when I'm trying to understand how a Wordpress theme was coded, I spend hours trying to figure out which php file is generating the element (for instance, a div or link).

Is there any way of detecting the PHP file?

Comment: yes sir, read the functions documentation in the wordpress edit theme section in your wordpress admin page

Comment: You can look into `debug_backtrace()` and/or `debug_print_backtrace()`. A bit unsure if this is what you're after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [debug_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) or [debug_print_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) to dig really deep and find out all kinds of information, such as when and where functions are called and files are loaded.

This is really useful for finding out `how a Wordpress theme was coded`. It will tell you pretty much everything.

Comment: So I jsut need to add those functions in the header?

Comment: Well, what specifically do you want to figure out?

Comment: There is a div in the Wordpress admin. I want to know where it is coming from (it is located in the main wrapper).

Comment: Oh.. OK, my mistake - I should have thought that this answer would not help. You're looking for the html, not the php. You are probably best off just searching in all the template files. There is also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which may give you better answers. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. You can still try debug_print_backtrace(), call it somewhere after the div would be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

well if you have xdebug and kcachegrind you can use kcachegrind to view the cachegrind output file of xdebug. there is also a php version called [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) that you can run on your local system if you are developing on your own computer before transfering the files to you server.

Comment: but if you are using wordpress the results might make you nauseous